# Python urlencode with double quotes

Tags: python, urllib, urlencode

I have a dict like this:

```
d = {'orderBy': 'XXXXX'}
```

When I call urlencode (), it transforms into:

```
orderBy = XXXXX
```

But I needed it to look like this:

```
orderBy = "XXXXX"
```

Does anyone know how I add these two quotes using urllib?
Thank you!

Comment: URL encoding does not normally add quotes, because that would make those double-quote characters part of the *value*. Why do you think you need those? Are you thinking of **JSON** encoding instead perhaps?

Comment: Put differently, if you need double quotes in a URL parameter, then you need to add those yourself, Python won't add those for you because that's not part of the URL encoding scheme.

Answer (score -1):

Just set your dict with the doble quotes:

```py
>>> d = { 'orderBy': '"XXXXX"' }
>>> urlencode(d)
'orderBy="XXXXX"'
```